# Automatic file saving from a DBGrid in Delphi - How Possible

Tags: file, delphi, dbgrid

I want to know whether there is a way to perform an automatic file saving without any dialogs.
I know how to manage with the JvDBGridCSVExport-Object the exportings and savings from a JvDBUltimGrid, but like I said I want savings without any Dialogs so that I can perform these actions automatic without any clickings. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a timer to call the export or save method when it fires.

You'll need to also set up a temporary filename that's valid so it doesn't raise an exception when it does do the save.